# How do you make value pairs and repeat them?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def cartesian_product(table1, table2):

    '''(table, table) -> table

    Return a table that is created by joining the tables table1 and table2. The
    cartesian products of the two tables is a new table where each row in the first 
    table is paired with every row in the second table. Each table is supposed to 
    be a dictionary.

    Example:

    dict1 = {'a': ['b', 'c']}
    dict2 = {'d': ['e', 'f']}
    cartesian_product({'a': ['b', 'c']}, {'d': ['e', 'f']})
    {'a': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'd': ['e', 'f', 'e', 'f']}

    '''

    table1 = list(table1.values())
    table2 = list(table2.values())

    for object1 in table1:
       x = object1

       for object2 in table2:
          y = object2

          return x,y
```

This is what I have so far and I know the output is:

```
(['b', 'c'], ['e', 'f'])
```

I want it to return:

```
{'a': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'd': ['e', 'f', 'e', 'f']}
```

I can try to return the dictionary myself -- but in the list -- how do you make pairs and repeat them?

Comment: why is it `['e', 'f', 'e', 'f']` and `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']`.  I'm not seeing the pattern here ...

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now; it is supposed to be a table of two rows; `b` and `e` are a pair, so are `b` and `f`, then `c` and `e` and `c` and `f`, etc.

Comment: Haha... fantastic... I had the answer for this yesterday... and the OP deleted their question... and now I can't find a saved copy :)

Comment: @JonClements: go to your answers tab; find a link to 'recently deleted answers' at the bottom. All answers deleted in the past 60 days are listed there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters didn't get a chance to post it :)

Comment: @JonClements: I channeled your memory and wrote it down below..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce pairs, which you can then append to your output:

```
from itertools import product

def cartesian_product(table1, table2):
    (table1_name, table1_columns), = table1.items()
    (table2_name, table2_columns), = table2.items()
    output = {table1_name: [], table2_name: []}
    for cola, colb in product(table1_columns, table2_columns):
        output[table1_name].append(cola)
        output[table2_name].append(colb)
    return output
```

or you can nest the loops:

```
def cartesian_product(table1, table2):
    (table1_name, table1_columns), = table1.items()
    (table2_name, table2_columns), = table2.items()
    output = {table1_name: [], table2_name: []}
    for cola in table1_columns:
        for colb in table2_columns:
            output[table1_name].append(cola)
            output[table2_name].append(colb)
    return output
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, my magical unicorn unicode key ran away.

Comment: I get what you did there, but i am not going to be importing a function. Can you elaborate on why you used the output for this function?

Comment: Do you mean `product()`? Because that function creates the exact same output as the nested loops, but without having to nest loops, basically. It is the canonical method for producing a carthesian product in Python code.

Comment: I realised I had not added the customary documentation link; I've done so now.